# Unable to change border color of a div

Tags: html, css

Could anybody help why am not able to change the border color from blue(by alert-info) to
$f0f0f0 ?

```
 <div
   class="alert alert-info"
   role="alert"
   border="2px solid #f0f0f0
   ></div>
```

Comment: Because that's not how you set styles on an element. Divs don't have a `border` attribute. Also, you're missing a closing quotation mark. You should be using a custom class and CSS, though, not inline styles.

Answer (score 0):

may be you inherit the parent css in your file

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="alert alert-info" style="border:5px solid #f0f0f0;" role="alert">
  This is a info alert—check it out!
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply border-color and border style property this would allow to set the color for the borders.I have provided a sample HTML code for your reference else add

HTML code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
h1 {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: coral;
}

div {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: coral;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>hello</h1>

<div>World</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code is not clear here but I will try to answer from what i can get.

```html
 <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert" style="border:2px solid #f0f0f0!important" ></div>
```

Try adding the border attribute in **style** tag and adding `!important` to the end.

Comment: adding imporant is never a good idea

Comment: you are correct but in beginner situations like this, it might help to overcome a simple problem, move on and learn more things. I was stucking with problems like this when I was a beginner, wish someone did this to me.